# LINQ query for comparing two objects?

Tags: c#, .net, json, linq

I need to return a subset of an object based off of a list of values in another object.

Object to return:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Title {get;set;}
    public Item subItems {get;set;}
}
```

I want to select a subset of "Items" based off of the items property on a User table:

```
public class User
{
    public string ID {get;set;}
    public Subscription[] subscriptions {get;set;}
}

public class Subscription
{
    public string Title {get;set;}
}
```

So, each User will have an array of subscriptions. I want to return an Item object for a specific user, where the Item Title is in the list of Titles within the user's subscription.

eg...

```
Items:[
{ title: "USA Today",
  otherdata: "..."},
{ title: "WSJ",
  otherdata: "..."},
{ title: "ET Weekly",
  otherdata: "..."}
]

Users: [
{ ID: "joe schmo",
  subscriptions" : [
    { item : "USA Today" },
    { item : "ET Weekly" }
  ]
}...]
```

In this example, I want to return :

```
items = [ {title : "USA Today"
           otherdata: "..."},
          {title: "ET Weekly",
           otherdata: "..."}
        ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have here is just two operations, one to flatten the sequence of users into the sequence of subscriptsions, and then a Join of the subscriptions with items on the `Title` property of each:

```
var query = from user in users
            from subscription in user.subscriptions
            join item in items
            on subscription.Title equals item.Title
            select item;
```